# Virtual templates?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to declare an abstract class, but just the act of templating a virtual function makes the compiler complain.  How is this normally accomplished? For example, in my header file I have:

```
virtual SpecialList<Point> *getPoints() const;
```

To which the compiler states "ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'SpecialList' with no type."

**edit**
Both Point and SpecialList are included in the definition of this class.  As a more verbose example,

```
// SomeClass.h
#include "SpecialList.h"
#include "Point.h"

class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass();
    virtual SpecialList<Point> *getPoints() const;
//snip
};
```

Still not solved..

Comment: Have you defined or included the Point class before your "virtual SpecialList<Point> *getPoints() const"?

Answer (score 5):

```
struct A
{
    virtual vector<int>* f() const = 0;
};
```

Works fine for me. Make sure that 'SpecialList' and 'Point' are defined before you use them.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you haven't defined `Point` before you're using it.

Define `Point` before the abstract class, or include the header file in which it's defined!

--

Or in case if you're trying to define virtual function template, something like this:

```
template<typename Point>
virtual SpecialList<Point> *getPoints() const;
```

Then it's not possible. virtual function template is not allowed!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you #included SpecialList and Point class declarations or forward-declarated or typedefed it.